# Replace key in nested maps

Tags: erlang, maps

How can i replace all keys in the nested map with another key without knowing the path (or replace keys, that match a pattern), for example:

```
Map = #{foo => #{bar => 1, foo => #{bar => 2}}}.
Map2 = maps:keyreplace(bar, foo, Map).
>>> #{foo => #{foo => 1, foo => #{foo => 2}}}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
Replacing key in a flat map seems to be pretty simple:

```
keyreplace(K1, K2, M) when is_map(M) ->
    case maps:take(K1, M) of
        {V, M2} ->
            maps:put(K2, V, M2);
        error -> M
    end.
```

Or like that, maybe:

```
keymap(F, Map) ->
    maps:fold(fun(K, V, Acc) ->
        maps:put(F(K), V, Acc)
    end, #{}, Map).
Map = #{foo => 1, bar => 2}.
Fun = fun(K) -> atom_to_list(K) end.
Map2 = keymap(Fun, Map).
>>> #{"bar" => 2,"foo" => 1}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote recursive function which you can use to achieve your goal, it takes 3 arguments:

Is_matched - function in which you check that key match your pattern.

Convert - function which converts key as you want.

Map - map to process.

```
replace_keys(Is_matched, Convert, Map) when is_map(Map) ->
  maps:fold(fun (K, V, AccIn) ->
    NewKey =
      case Is_matched(K) of
        true -> Convert(K);
        false -> K
      end,
    maps:put(NewKey, replace_keys(Is_matched, Convert, V), AccIn)
  end, #{}, Map);

replace_keys(_, _, Term) -> Term.
```

Example:

```
1> Map = #{a => "1", <<"b">> => #{c => "2", <<"d">> => 3}}.            
#{a => "1",<<"b">> => #{c => "2",<<"d">> => 3}}
2> Is_matched = fun(Term) -> is_atom(Term) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.99386804>
3> Convert = fun(Term) -> atom_to_list(Term) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.99386804>
4> keyreplace:replace_keys(Is_matched, Convert, Map).
#{"a" => "1",<<"b">> => #{"c" => "2",<<"d">> => 3}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with some modifications to your `maps:fold` attempt:

1. If the third argument is not a map, return it as is.
2. When folding:

   1. Recursively call the function with the value field to obtain the new value.
   2. If the key matches K1, put the new value into K2.

Your example output is incorrect - it has 2 values for the `foo` key. I've modified it in the test below.

```
keyreplace(K1, K2, Map) when is_map(Map) ->
  maps:fold(fun(K, V, Acc) ->
    Key = if K == K1 -> K2; true -> K end,
    Value = keyreplace(K1, K2, V),
    maps:put(Key, Value, Acc)
  end, #{}, Map);
keyreplace(_K1, _K2, Term) -> Term.
```

```
1> c(a).
{ok,a}
2> Map = #{foo => #{bar => 1, baz => #{bar => 2}}}.
#{foo => #{bar => 1,baz => #{bar => 2}}}
3> a:keyreplace(bar, foo, Map).
#{foo => #{baz => #{foo => 2},foo => 1}}
```